# some customers struck in checkout process

Tags: checkout, customer-account

we are facing a strangest problem ever in live site.

for **some** registered customers [email id ], when they enter Billing address and click on "**continue**" button,

**its not moving to the next step. Instead of this ,its coming back to the previous step.**

we are using https for checkout. This is ajax response :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please  provide more details

Comment: its strange, for some customers, they can not able to place the order and some customers can place the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be remove Shipping Address step on checkout page.

But on  checkout billing step ,you have set **`billing[use_for_shipping]`** value as **0**.For this 0 value you need to got at shipping address step but it is not exit;

So You need to  set  **`billing[use_for_shipping]`** value as **1** (Means Ship to same address) to directly goto at Shipping method step Ship to this address